# Crash in CFNetwork CFAllocatedReferenceCountedObject::_retainable_hash(void const*)

Tags: ios, swift, crash, cfnetwork, cfnetworking

Crash logs: 
1 CRASH
1 USER

CFNetwork
CFAllocatedReferenceCountedObject::_retainable_hash(void const*)

Crashed: com.apple.CFNetwork.LoaderQ

```
0  CFNetwork                      0x183985310 CFAllocatedReferenceCountedObject::_retainable_hash(void const*) + 26 
1  CoreFoundation                 0x18321e160 CFBasicHashFindBucket + 164 
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18321e0a0 CFDictionaryGetValue
    + 224 
3  CFNetwork                      0x1839b5a4c TubeManager::_onqueue_enqueueRequestForProtocol(MetaConnectionCacheClient*, HTTPRequestMessage const*, MetaConnectionOptions, BaseAwaitingTube*) + 80 
4  CFNetwork                      0x1839b69b4 TubeManager::_onqueue_reenqueueAwaitingTube(BaseAwaitingTube*) + 112 
5 CFNetwork                      0x1839b6c14 invocation function for block in TubeManager::_onqueue_newTubeReady(Tube*, CFStreamError) + 28 
6  CFNetwork                      0x183b152e4 invocation function for block in QCoreSchedulingSet::performAsync(void () block_pointer) const
    + 52 
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x182cdea54 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x182cdea14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 
9  libdispatch.dylib         0x182ce896c _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 528 
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ce92fc
    _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340 
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ce8824 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 200 
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ce92fc
    _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340 
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ce9d20 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 404 
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x182cf203c
    _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 644 
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182f86f1c _pthread_wqthread + 932 
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182f86b6c start_wqthread + 4
```

IOS versions: 
11.2.6
11.2.2
11.2.1

Devices: 
iPhone 6 
iPhone 6S plus
iPad mini 2

Does somebody know why this error occurs and how to solve it? 
Please help